# A question about local connectedness in metric spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology

Must every compact and connected metric space be locally connected at at least one
of its points?

Comment: Umm.. I just noticed that the answer to this was given more than a year ago to another question made by you on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36488/a-question-about-local-connectedness/36497#36497

Answer (score 7):

There is a "folklore" counterexample. Peter Nyikos gives the construction [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=3297) (see the last paragraph for the compactness)

Comment: I assume it's folklore, but people more versed in this sort of thing may know differently...

Comment: Nyikos' example seems fine, but I think he incorrectly uses positive slopes for the "left fan" and negative slopes for the "right fan."  I see it making more sense with positive slopes in both.

Comment: It's one of those examples where the picture is much easier to comprehend than the description.

Comment: And yes, the picture would seem to have slopes being positive in both fans.

Answer (score 5):

One more picture: [Brouwer--Janiszewski--Knaster continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the product of the closet unit interval $I$ with the Cantor set $C$, identify $(0,x)$ and $\big(1,f(x)\big)$  where $f(x):=3x \mod 1$.

The resulting space $X$ is  the [mapping cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cylinder) of the continuous  map $f:C\to C$. 
It is a compact metric space locally homeomorphic to $]0,1[\times C\, ,$ thus not locally connected at any point. End-points of $I$ have not a special role; we may equivalently obtain $X$ with a larger quotient, $(\mathbb{R}\times C) / \{ (t,x)=\big (t+1,f(x)\big) \} $. 
The important feature of the map $f:C\to C$ is that it has a dense orbit $f^n( x_0)$. This is easily seen as it is conjugate  to the left-shift map on binary strings on the space ${\bf 2}^\mathbb{N}$, $(c_1,c_2,\dots)\mapsto(c_2,c_3,\dots)$ which is just how we see $f$ on the 2-digits representations of points of the Cantor set. As a consequence, the image of $\mathbb{R}\times \{x_0\}$ in the latter quotient is a path-connected dense subset of $X$, which is therefore connected.

**edit.** Actually, such spaces are quite common in dynamical systems; an other example is the Smale-Williams [Solenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_%28mathematics%29) and several [strange attractors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_attractor#Strange_attractor).

Answer (score 4):

The two examples given so far do not contain an illustration of the set. So here is one drawn with a *"Cantor-pen"*:

[image] [(source)](http://users.jyu.fi/~tamaraja/temp/mo.gif)

Answer (score 1):

No, examples abound, e.g., the $\sin\frac1x$-curve, i.e., the closure of 
$\lbrace \sin\frac1x : 0 < x \le 1\rbrace$ in the plane. As noted below, this is not a good example (I misread the question).

However, every [indecomposable continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum), such as Knaster's bucket-handle continuum, is an example because every proper subcontinuum is nowhere dense. The [pseudo-arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoarc) is, of course the ultimate example.

Comment: not this one: it has tons of points with locally connected neighbourhoods: anything off the $y$ axis

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the question but I added the bucket handle just to be sure. There's also the pseudoarc of course.

Comment: I am really embarassed and must apologize to everyone for failing to
keep track of some of my past questions-in particular No.36488. As 
Tapio Rajala has pointed out, this question is almost a duplicate of
my present question and the very neat answer to it given by Victor 
Protsak also answers my present question-which should probably be
closed out on the grounds of almost duplicating a previous question.
Many thanks to all of you for your excellent answers which I was
never quite able to discover for myself.
